# Without integrating, show that $\frac{3}{2\pi}\int_{-a}^a\int_{-a}^a\frac{a}{(a^2+y^2+z^2)^{3/2}}dydz$ is independent of (positive) $a$

Tags: calculus

I know that, for $a>0$, this integral is constant (in fact, $1$):
$$\frac{3}{2\pi}\int_{-a}^a\int_{-a}^a\frac{a}{\left(\;a^2+y^2+z^2\;\right)^{\;3/2}}dydz$$

How can I prove that the expression does not depend on the value of $a$, without solving the integral?

Comment: Have you tried differentiating it with respect to $a$?  That should give $0$.  I haven't tried it.

Comment: How do I do a derivative of something like this?

Comment: The differential of an integral with respect to a limit is the value of the integrand at that limit.  You also have to add the integral of the deriviative of the integrand with respect to $a$ over the interval.  It comes out of the chain rule.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change variables  $u=y/a$ and $v=z/a$. Then the integral does not depend on $a$.

Comment: Wouldn't you get $\frac{3}{2\pi}\int_{-1}^1\int_{-1}^1\frac{1}{\left(\;1+u^2+v^2\;\right)^{\;3/2}}a^2dudv$

Comment: No, you don't have $a^2$

Comment: But $u=y/a \implies a*du=dy $, so you should have an a^2. How does it go away?

Comment: Oh wait, it cancels out in the denominator.